# How to get row as array in postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am using RAW PostgreSQL query in nestjs - query builder.

**My query :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    user.id,
    ARRAY_AGG(fct.fanname) AS name
FROM
    users u
    LEFT JOIN user_fans ufe ON ufe.fanid = u.id
    LEFT JOIN fans fct ON fct.id = ufe.fanid
WHERE
    u.id = 1
GROUP BY
    u.id,
    ufe.id,
    fct.id
ORDER BY
    u.id
```

My problem is resulting table is shown as below :

| id | fanname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fan1 |
| 1 | fan2 |

I tried the array aggregator function and still fails to get expected result as below.

| id | fanname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | fan1 ,fan2 |

Table images links : 3 tables user , user_fans, fans
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2jzG.png)

Comment: perhaps `group by user.id` only? ;)

Comment: Additionally: the `distinct` is useless if you are also grouping.

Comment: @JimJones used only "group by user.id" . I am getting error - "column \"fct.fanname\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function""

Comment: removed distinct. But output is same as before. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: The above query will _not_ generate the error "*column "fct.fanname" must appear in the GROUP BY clause*" if you use `group by u.id`

Comment: @noobdev6576576 to avoid misunderstandings, consider adding the `create table` and `insert` statements in a fiddle, so that we can better reproduce your issue. e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30

Comment: @JimJones https://dbfiddle.uk/XMkSgee4 here is the full table . you can see the result as above . Any help would be great full.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but I dont know why  am getting error > ERROR:  column "ufe.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: select u.user_id,ARRAY_AGG(fct.fan_name) AS name,ufe.user_id : from https://dbfiddle.uk/UkQHLyLN virtual db 
                                                         ^

Comment: remove `,ufe.user_id` from the SELECT list https://dbfiddle.uk/rpP12RaD